# How enable cors for html files?

Tags: django, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using cloudfront to distribute my static files from S3 bucket. I'm using django as my backend. I configurated my cloudfront to get my static files from my S3 bucket. For `images` and `css` and `js` files works well. But for `html` files is getting this error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/static/partials/main.html?v=e720c74cfb39a5d17a1f5b4d75a496df30620a5c' from origin 'https://www.xxxxxxx.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

But the problem is my others files are download normally, why my html files are getting these erros.

I have `django-cors-headers==1.1.0` installed in my pip, and i enable all `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`. But still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind posting your `settings.py` configuration?

In addition to the steps you have taken, `'corsheaders'` needs to be added to your `INSTALLED_APPS` and `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'` to the ***top*** of `MIDDLEWARE`

Best of luck!